# Problemas con el pip install

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, pip

He querido instalar las librerías ttk pero no me deja, lo mismo para instalar Tkinter, trate con pip y no encontró nada, también intenté descargarlas con Pycharm pero igual no me deja.

Lo estoy intentando con Python 2.7 y 3.6

Comment: que mensaje muestra cuando tratas de instalar ?

Comment: C:\Users\Jorge Ceron>pip install tkinter
Collecting tkinter
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions
: )
No matching distribution found for tkinter
Lo mismo con Tkinter y Tk

Comment: ok es windows, que Python version tienes en este momento?

Comment: Que muestra pip -V

Comment: Tkinter es parte de python, no hace falta instalarlo con pip. Estas seguro que estas importando la librería correctamente con `import tkinter`?

Comment: si, puedo importar tkinter en 3.6 en 2.7 no lo hace. estoy en 2.7 por default

Comment: de hecho tkinter si lo puedo usar (aunque solo en 3.6) lo que no puedo importar es ttk, no se porque no me deja esa libreria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te han comentado tanto `Tkinter` como `Ttk` son parte de la biblioteca estandar de Python, por lo tanto no tiene sentido intentar usar `pip` para instalarla.

Dicho esto el problema puede ser  la forma de importarlas. En `Python 2.x` `Ttk` es un módulo externo a `Tkinter` mientras que en `Python 3.x` forma parte del mismo paquete. Para importarlo una forma muy común es:

**Python 3.x:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
```

**Python 2.x:**

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
```

**Observa que en `Python 2.x` el módulo `Tkinter` es con mayúscula y en `Python 3.x` es con minúscula.**

De esta forma no sobreescribes los widgets nativos de Tkinter con los de Ttk haciendo el código mucho más legible al explicitar siempre que toolkit estás usando en cada momento.

Un ejemplo de uso:

- **Python 3.x:**

  ```
  import tkinter as tk
  from tkinter import ttk

  master = tk.Tk()

  def callback1():
      print ("Click en el boton de tkinter")

  def callback2():
      print ("Click en el boton de ttk")

  boton1 = tk.Button(master, text="Tkinter", command=callback1)
  boton2 = ttk.Button(master, text="ttk", command=callback2)
  boton1.pack()
  boton2.pack()

  master.mainloop()
  ```
- **Python 2.x:**

  ```
  import Tkinter as tk
  import ttk

  master = tk.Tk()

  def callback1():
      print ("Click en el boton de tkinter")

  def callback2():
      print ("Click en el boton de ttk")

  boton1 = tk.Button(master, text="Tkinter", command=callback1)
  boton2 = ttk.Button(master, text="ttk", command=callback2)
  boton1.pack()
  boton2.pack()

  master.mainloop()
  ```

`boton1` es un botón nativo de `Tkinter` mientras que `boton2` es un botón 'mejorado' de la extensión `Ttk`.

Puedes ver más sobre Tkinter y su uso en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tk.html) oficial de Python.

Si estos códigos te dan error edita la pregunta y aporta el error que te marca, el código que usas y la forma de importar los módulos para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: Intenté correr el codigo que pusiste y funciono bien, solo que cambie de computadora. Debo de tener algun problema con las versiones de Python, voy a reinstalar todo.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda